# Rails: How can I use a loop to create a list of checkboxes using form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a form with a list of checkboxes.

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: creators_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <% Subject.all.each do |subject| %>
    <%= f.label subject.name %>
    <%= f.check_box :subject_ids, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I want the resulting user_params to contain an array of the ids of chosen subjects.

With the above code, I get:

```
> params.require(:user)
  <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"John", "subject_ids"=>"0"} permitted: true>
```

But I want "subject_ids" to be an array:

```
> params.require(:user)
  <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"John", "subject_ids"=>[0,1,2,3]} permitted: true>
```

What is the correct way to handle collections in a Rails form?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using strong params like this

```
def safe_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, subject_ids: [])
end
```

and in your actions

```
def create
  ..
  safe_params[:subject_ids] # will now be an array
  ..
end
```